# How do I prefix rails and rake commands with foreman automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, heroku, foreman

When I'm in a Rails project, how do I save myself from typing

```
foreman run rails console
```

every time?  In other words, is there a way to automatically prefix `rails` and `rake` commands with `foreman run` automatically?

Comment: I assume it's in a local dev env. Why not use a shell alias?

Comment: I have multiple Rails projects and they don't all use Heroku.  I assume you mean I should put `alias rails=foreman run rails` in my `~/.bash_profile` but this is too wide of a scope.  Ideally the alias would be confined to just this project's root.

Comment: Something like that, yes. Don't you have a shell script that you run when you "start working on a project", that sets environment variables, paths, changes the prompt, etc. anyways? Add the alias there.

Comment: Or just change the alias name, or make a function that checks if it uses Heroku or not, and then either calls `foreman run rails` or just `rails`.

Comment: In response to Nitzan, unfortunately I don't have a script like that.  BroSlow, can you give me an example?

Comment: You can just make an array of `Heroku` projects and check your `PWD` against it in the function. Might be an easier option for rails as well though don't know it offhand. Can post an example of your directory structure with some `Heroku` and non-`Heroku` projects?

Comment: just give the foreman alias a different name, like `alias frails=foreman run rails`. Then you can use `frails console` in Heroku apps and `rails console` elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a bash function:

```
rails () {
    if test current directory is in a rails project  # left as an exercise
    then
        foreman run rails "$@"
    else
        command rails "$@"
    fi
}
```

Comment: I'm going to check for the existence of an `.env` file in project root which should be a fair indication of Heroku.  Thank you.